# Why usage of async block in then makes my Stream Unpin?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'm sorry if I'm using terms incorrect. Maybe my choice of words for question is incorrect.

I was playing with streams and I needed to have some delay between stream elements. So I wrote this:

```
use futures::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = stream::iter(0..1000).then(|x| async move {
        time::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        x + 1
    });
    while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x)
    }
}
```

I get a lot of compilation errors, but the most important errors are connected with pinning. Here they are:

```
error[E0277]: `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:7:64: 10:6 x:_ _]>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:11:32
   |
11 |     while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
   |                                ^^^^ within `futures_util::stream::stream::then::_::__Then<'_, futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`, the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:7:64: 10:6 x:_ _]>`
   |
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<impl core::future::future::Future>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures_util::stream::stream::then::_::__Then<'_, futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Unpin` for `futures_util::stream::stream::then::Then<futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`

error[E0277]: `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:7:64: 10:6 x:_ _]>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:11:25
   |
11 |     while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ within `futures_util::stream::stream::then::_::__Then<'_, futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`, the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:7:64: 10:6 x:_ _]>`
   |
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<impl core::future::future::Future>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures_util::stream::stream::then::_::__Then<'_, futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Unpin` for `futures_util::stream::stream::then::Then<futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `core::future::future::Future` for `futures_util::stream::stream::next::Next<'_, futures_util::stream::stream::then::Then<futures_util::stream::iter::Iter<std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, impl core::future::future::Future, [closure@src/main.rs:7:49: 10:6]>>`
```

If I change my code to this:

```
use futures::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut stream = stream::iter(0..1000).then(|x|  {
        futures::future::ready(x + 1)
    });
    while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x)
    }
}
```

Or to this:

```
use futures::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::time;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    stream::iter(0..1000)
        .then(|x| async move {
            time::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
            x + 1
        })
        .for_each(|x| async move { println!("{:?}", x) })
        .await;
}
```

It compiles.

I assume it has something to do with pinning and simultaneous usage of `then` combinator and `while`, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the issue boils down to the fact that `async` blocks are not `Unpin`. It can be proven with this code:

```
fn check_unpin<F: Unpin>(_: F) { }

fn main() {
    check_unpin(async {});
}
```

that fails with the rather cryptic message:

```
error[E0277]: `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:4:23: 4:25 _]>` cannot be unpinned
  --> src/main.rs:4:5
   |
1  | fn check_unpin<F: Unpin>(_: F) { }
   |                   ----- required by this bound in `check_unpin`
...
4  |     check_unpin(async {});
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ within `impl std::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Unpin` is not implemented for `std::future::from_generator::GenFuture<[static generator@src/main.rs:4:23: 4:25 _]>`
   |
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl std::future::Future`
```

I reckon that `GenFuture` is the internal type that converts an `async` block into a `impl Future`.

Now back to your issue, the combinator `then()` returns an `Unpin` value if both the stream and the `Future` returned by the closure are `Unpin` (it is not totally clear in the [documentation](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.5/futures_util/stream/struct.Then.html#impl-Unpin), but I've inferred that from the source code). The `stream::iter` [is](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.5/futures_util/stream/struct.Iter.html#impl-Unpin) `Unpin`, but when you write `|x| async move { x + 1}` you are returning an `async` block that is not `Unpin`, thus your error.

If you use `futures::future::ready(x + 1)` it works simply because that `Future` [implements](https://docs.rs/futures-util/0.3.5/futures_util/future/struct.Ready.html#impl-Unpin) `Unpin`.

If you use `StreamExt::for_each` it works because it does not require `Self` to be `Unpin`. It is not `Unpin` itself, but it does not matter because you are sending it up to `tokio::main` that pins everything internally before polling.

If you want your original code to work you just have to manually pin your stream ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa413b567dd0b1d95c74da557b9c67a0)):

```
use futures::stream;
use futures::StreamExt;
use tokio::time;
use pin_utils::pin_mut;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let stream = stream::iter(0..1000).then(|x| async move {
        time::delay_for(std::time::Duration::from_millis(500)).await;
        x + 1
    });
    pin_mut!(stream); //<---- here, pinned!
    while let Some(x) = stream.next().await {
        println!("{:?}", x)
    }
}
```